# Evaluate Character and Numeric Variables in PROC SQL

Tags: sql, macros, sas

I am trying to evaluate whether or not a variable is character or numeric within PROC SQL.  This will then determine which WHERE clause to use.  I thought using VTYPE would give me the results I wanted, but it sounds like you cannot use that function within PROC SQL.  Is there a specific function that can be used within PROC SQL, which will return the variable type and be evaluated in the if statement?  How would that function be incorporated into the SQL code?

My full code is below:

```
%MACRO miss_count(vars=,dataset=,business_line=);
PROC SQL;
SELECT s1.&vars, s1.year AS years, 
COUNT(*) AS missing, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM saslib.&dataset AS s2 WHERE s2.year=s1.year) AS total, 
(COUNT(*)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM saslib.&dataset AS s3 WHERE s3.year=s1.year))*100 AS perc_missing
FROM saslib.&dataset AS s1
%IF VTYPE(&vars) = 'C' %THEN WHERE s1.&vars IN (' ', 'UNKN', 'NONE') %ELSE WHERE s1.&vars IN (.)
AND s1.bus_line = &business_line
GROUP BY s1.&vars, s1.year;
QUIT;
%MEND miss_count;

%miss_count(vars=cpt_typcode, dataset=sample, business_line='COM')
```

However, when I run this code I get the error:

```
ERROR: Required operator not found in expression: VTYPE(&vars) = 'C' 
ERROR: The macro MISS_COUNT will stop executing.
```

I am pretty new to SAS and I am wondering how to evaluate whether a variable is character or numeric in PROC SQL.

For more information, the output is listed below.

```
MLOGIC(MISS_COUNT):  Beginning execution.
MLOGIC(MISS_COUNT):  Parameter VARS has value cpt_typcode
MLOGIC(MISS_COUNT):  Parameter DATASET has value sample
MLOGIC(MISS_COUNT):  Parameter BUSINESS_LINE has value 'COM'
MPRINT(MISS_COUNT):   PROC SQL;
ERROR: Required operator not found in expression: VTYPE(&vars) = 'C' 
ERROR: The macro MISS_COUNT will stop executing.
MPRINT(MISS_COUNT):   SELECT s1.cpt_typcode, s1.year AS years, COUNT(*) AS missing, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM saslib.sample AS s2 WHERE 
s2.year=s1.year) AS total, (COUNT(*)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM saslib.sample AS s3 WHERE s3.year=s1.year))*100 AS perc_missing FROM 
saslib.sample AS s1
MLOGIC(MISS_COUNT):  Ending execution.
```

Comment: In addition to the problem of `if` vs `%if`, VTYPE isn't usable in SQL; it is a data step only function.

Comment: If you edit the question to remove the issue of the `%if` (which I think dominates the other issue right now), it could still be a good question (reworded to focus on the issue of how you write the SQL so that it works with numeric or character, OR how to write the macro so to get variable type into a macro variable), and I'd reopen it.

Comment: Is it possible to use missing value as a way to determine whether the variable belongs to character or numeric i.e a dot or a blank. A sql join could evaluate missing values easily